# How to return queue message to Azure Service Bus Queue if Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger Func Fails

Tags: python, azure, serverless, azure-servicebus-queues

I created an **Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger Python Function** with **Visual Studio Code** and I would like to return the **message** to the **Service Bus Queue** if my code **fails**.

```py
import requests
import azure.functions as func
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    message = msg.get_body().decode("utf-8")

    url = "http://..."

    # My code
    try: 
         requests.post(url=url, params=message)
    except Exception as error:
         logging.error(error)
         # RETURN MESSAGE TO QUEUE HERE
```

I found some info about a method called **unlock()** and **abandon()** but I don't know how to implement it. Here are the links to such docs:

- unlock: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues#handle-application-crashes-and-unreadable-messages
- abandon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.common.message.deferredmessage?view=azure-python#abandon--

I also found that the queue would automatically send the message to the queue if the function fails, but then, should I write a **raise...** to send an Exception in the function?

Also, is there a way to return this message to the **queue** and set a **schedule** to retry later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service bus trigger python function runs in PeekLock mode. You don't have to call unlock() and abandon() method. Check the [PeekLock behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python#peeklock-behavior) description:

> The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode. It calls
>   Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or
>   calls Abandon if the function fails. If the function runs longer than
>   the PeekLock timeout, the lock is automatically renewed as long as the
>   function is running.

Comment: Thank you, what I find interesting about this is, should I catch the Exceptions, Log them and then raise NameOfTheException? to make it fail? Or should I remove try/except operations in the code and let the function fail?